# How can we decrease elasticsearch query clauses count?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have written an elasticsearch query for get grouped data from an index for specific date range. However, if we increase date range, our query size increased with dynamically added date range clauses. 
dynamicaly increase query sample

```
 "query": {
"bool": {
  "filter": [
    {
      "bool": {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "startDate": {
                "gte": "2018-05-28T21:00:00Z",
                "lte": "2021-04-04T20:59:59Z"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "startDate": {
                      "gte": "2019-12-24T04:30:00Z",
                      "lte": "2019-12-24T14:00:00Z"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "startDate": {
                      "gte": "2020-11-09T04:30:00Z",
                      "lte": "2020-11-09T14:00:00Z"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "startDate": {
                      "gte": "2020-07-28T14:00:00Z",
                      "lte": "2020-07-28T20:59:00Z"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "tenantId": {
          "value": "b29aadd8-b1bb-4754-ab26-b59eebe6d86a"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "status.keyword": {
          "value": "ProductionEnd"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "startDate": {
          "gte": "2018-05-28T21:00:00Z",
          "lte": "2021-04-04T20:59:59Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}},
```

We have time based data and we want to filter them by datetime like above but we want to filter 3 months range of data and there will be too much range filter and we get an error(***"too_many_clauses"***) because of query size. So, we want to decrease the query clauses. How can we rewrite the query?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering why you want to build so many range queries instead of one for `from start date to end date`?

Comment: Because just one date range is not enough. We give a date range for whole data and each day has a few time range . You can think a day separate with shifts. So we have to get each shift range datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the options for you is to split such big should query into smaller chunks of should queries. This way no bool query expands limit of 1024 clauses.

```
bool
|___should
|   |___should query with 1024 range queries 
|   |___should query with 1024 range queries 
|   |___...  range queries
```

Here is a simple example of what I'm talking about

```
var ranges = Enumerable.Range(0, 3000).Select((x, i) =>
    new QueryContainer(new DateRangeQuery {Name = $"query_{i}", Field = $"date", GreaterThan = "now"}));

var part1 = ranges.Take(1024)
    .Aggregate((agg, q) => agg || q);
var part2 = ranges.Skip(1024).Take(1024)
    .Aggregate((agg, q) => agg || q);

var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<object>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Should(part1, part2))));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob  :) Your answer helped a lot :)